# Visual Studio missing Platform Builder and Remote Tools

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging, platform-builder

I got Visual Studio set up exactly as I want and need.  Then my company acquired a computer upgrade for me and I have to reinstall everything.

Missing from the new configuration is Platform Builder and Remote Tools.  How do I aquire these?  I have tried searching and downloading what I thought would help me, but I am still missing these items from the "Tools" drop down menu in Visual studio.

I am going to include two massive texts.  They were acquired by clicking on "Help" --> "About Microsoft Visual Studio" and then in the window, clicking on "Copy Info" and pasting them here.

===========================

First, from the computer set up that works:

===========================

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
Version 9.0.30729.1 SP
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 3.5 SP1

Installed Edition: Professional

Microsoft Visual Basic 2008   91605-270-1823734-60867
Microsoft Visual Basic 2008

Microsoft Visual C# 2008   91605-270-1823734-60867
Microsoft Visual C# 2008

Microsoft Visual C++ 2008   91605-270-1823734-60867
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Tools for Office   91605-270-1823734-60867
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Tools for Office

Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008   91605-270-1823734-60867
Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008

Crystal Reports    AAJ60-G0MSA4K-68000CF
Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB2483802)   KB2483802
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2483802.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB2538241)   KB2538241
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2538241.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB944899)   KB944899
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/944899.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB945282)   KB945282
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945282.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB946040)   KB946040
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946040.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB946308)   KB946308
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946308.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB946344)   KB946344
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946344.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB946581)   KB946581
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946581.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB947171)   KB947171
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947171.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB947173)   KB947173
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947173.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB947180)   KB947180
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947180.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB947540)   KB947540
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947540.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB947789)   KB947789
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947789.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB948127)   KB948127
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948127.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB953256)   KB953256
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953256.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB971091)   KB971091
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971091.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB973674)   KB973674
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973674.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU Service Pack 1 (KB945140)   KB945140
This service pack is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this service pack will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945140.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU Service Pack 1 (KB947888)   KB947888
This service pack is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this service pack will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947888.

Platform Builder
Platform Builder (1687)

Remote Tools Framework Bundle Input Editor   9.0
Editor for cebundleinfo files

Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB2251487)   KB2251487
This security update is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this security update will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2251487.

Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB2669970)   KB2669970
This security update is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this security update will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2669970.

Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB972222)   KB972222
This security update is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this security update will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972222.

Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB956453)   KB956453
This update is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this update will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956453.

Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB967143)   KB967143
This update is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this update will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967143.

Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB972221)   KB972221
This update is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this update will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972221.

Windows Embedded Silverlight Tools   03349-785-0000007-70824
Windows Embedded Silverlight Tools
Version 3.0.2854.0

===========================

Now from the set up that does not work:

===========================

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
Version 9.0.30729.1 SP
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 3.5 SP1

Installed Edition: Professional

Microsoft Visual Basic 2008   91605-270-4806962-60494
Microsoft Visual Basic 2008

Microsoft Visual C# 2008   91605-270-4806962-60494
Microsoft Visual C# 2008

Microsoft Visual C++ 2008   91605-270-4806962-60494
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Tools for Office   91605-270-4806962-60494
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Tools for Office

Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008   91605-270-4806962-60494
Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008

Crystal Reports    AAJ60-G0MSA4K-68000CF
Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB2538241)   KB2538241
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2538241.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB944899)   KB944899
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/944899.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB945282)   KB945282
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945282.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB946040)   KB946040
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946040.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB946308)   KB946308
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946308.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB946344)   KB946344
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946344.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB946581)   KB946581
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946581.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB947171)   KB947171
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947171.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB947173)   KB947173
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947173.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB947180)   KB947180
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947180.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB947540)   KB947540
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947540.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB947789)   KB947789
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947789.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB948127)   KB948127
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948127.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB953256)   KB953256
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953256.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB971091)   KB971091
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971091.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB973674)   KB973674
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973674.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU Service Pack 1 (KB945140)   KB945140
This service pack is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this service pack will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945140.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU Service Pack 1 (KB947888)   KB947888
This service pack is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this service pack will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947888.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU Service Pack 1 (KB948484)   KB948484
This service pack is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this service pack will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948484.

Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB2251487)   KB2251487
This security update is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this security update will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2251487.

Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB2669970)   KB2669970
This security update is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this security update will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2669970.

Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB972222)   KB972222
This security update is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this security update will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972222.

Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB956453)   KB956453
This update is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this update will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956453.

Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB967143)   KB967143
This update is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this update will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967143.

Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB972221)   KB972221
This update is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this update will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972221.

Windows Embedded Silverlight Tools   03349-785-0000007-70824
Windows Embedded Silverlight Tools
Version 3.0.2854.0

Answer (score 0):

Platform Builder 7.0 is a separate download; it is not included in the VS2008 installation.

You can download a [180-day evaluation version](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/downloads.aspx) from Microsoft.

The full version is available through [Microsoft distributors](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/purchase.aspx), or if you have an MSDN subscription you can get it from the [Downloads section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/default.aspx).

Remote Tools is part of Platform Builder.